# Regex for mobile numbers with country codes

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression like thus:-

```
^
 (\+?(?![0])\d{1,2})?
 (00\d{2})?
 ([0-9]{10,10})
$
```

My test data is as follows:-

```
1. +447531234123 - pass
2. 447531234123 - pass
3. 00447531234123 - pass
4. 07531234123 - fail
5. 7531234123 - match
```

`1-4` are all correct. `#5` is incorrect. I'd like make all numbers fail if they aren't preceeded by `+44, 44` or `0044`. So, if one of the first *two groups* don't match - the third should fail.

Comment: Do you mean something like `^(?:\+|00)?44\d{10}$`?

Comment: Looks good, thankyou very much.

Comment: Welcome. with that confirmation I added the answer below. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are after:

```
^(?:\+|00)?44\d{10}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfHejA/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\+|00` - A literal plus **or** a double zero.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
- `44\d{10}` - Literally 44 followed by 10 digits.
- `$` - End line anchor.

**Edit:**
For *all* country codes, rather than the hard-coded `44` please use:-

```
/^(?:\+|00)?([1-9]){2}?\d{9,10}$/
```